# Is there a better way to set a property common to a list of items in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following class:

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateManufactured { get; set; }
}
```

I then made a list of vehicles like:

```
        var dateTime1 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
        var dateTime2 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-8);
        var dateTime3 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-9);

        var vehicles = new List<Vehicle>
            {
                new Vehicle {Make = "Ferrari", DateManufactured = dateTime1},
                new Vehicle {Make = "Mazda", DateManufactured = dateTime2},
                new Vehicle {Make = "Dodge", DateManufactured = dateTime3},
                new Vehicle {Make = "Holden", DateManufactured = dateTime1},
                new Vehicle {Make = "Chrysler", DateManufactured = dateTime2},
                new Vehicle {Make = "Mazda", DateManufactured = dateTime3},
            };
```

Next I was trying to get a list of DatesManufactured and for each date the vehicles that were manufactured on that date.

So I went for:

```
var vehiclesGroupedByDate = vechicles.GroupBy(x => x.DateManufactured)
                .Select(x => new
                    {
                        x.First().DateManufactured,
                        Vehicles = x.ToList()
                    });
```

This works fines but I'm not sure about the `x.First()` part. It works but it doesn't feel quite right. Does anybody know of a more elegant way to code this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use `GroupBy`, it will create an `IGrouping<TKey, TItem>`, so you can simply do the following:

```
var vehiclesGroupedByDate = vechicles.GroupBy(x => x.DateManufactured)
            .Select(x => new
                {
                    x.Key,
                    Vehicles = x.ToList()
                });
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't see anything wrong with your code, but you can also use `x.Key` instead of `x.First().DateManufactured` which wouldn't require a creation of an another IEnumerable.

Answer (score 3):

GroupBy exposes a Key property:

```
var vehiclesGroupedByDate = vechicles.GroupBy(x => x.DateManufactured)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        x.Key,
        Vehicles = x.ToList()
    });
```